# ThumbnailUtils not working

Tags: java, android, bitmap, thumbnails

I am using `ThumbnailUtils` for getting thumbnail as an image and setting it as an imagebutton. But it doesn't change anything. I am not getting anything, not even an empty thumbnail. How can I solve this ?

I have tried the following code :

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String animal = mData.get(position);
        holder.myTextView.setText(animal);
        int THUMBSIZE = 64;
        Bitmap ThumbImage = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(animal),
                THUMBSIZE, THUMBSIZE);
        if(animal!= null && animal.endsWith(".jpeg")){
            holder.myImage.setImageBitmap(ThumbImage);
        }
        }
```

*I am not sure how much code is sufficient or too much , I can add full code if required (just trying to keep it minimum so that question doesn't get downloaded)*

Comment: Did you check the image extension ".jpeg" or ".jpg"

Comment: yes , if I  use `setImageResouce` to use an image in drawable folder, it works fine

Comment: did you put a break point on thumbimage and check whether its null or not?

Comment: whats the size of `ThumbImage` (`ThumbImage.getWidth()` and `ThumbImage.getHeight()`)?

Comment: but actually most likely `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(animal)` simply returns null, double check it

Comment: you are right, it returns null @pskink. Thanks